# How do you organize your Models/Views/ViewModels in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

This has been a constant irritation of mine, so I thought I would ask for suggestions. How do you organize your Models/Views/ViewModels in WPF (Solution Explorer)? I can never seem to find a solution that I'm happy with so I'm wondering if there is someone out there that has.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Aside from the fact that your Models should be in their own assembly (project). I tend to put Related Views and ViewModels together in a single Folder, rather than having a folder called "Views" and Another one called "ViewModels"

Say, for example:

```
Project MyApp.Model
    |---> Models


Project MyApp.Client
    |--> Orders
    |      |--> OrderCRUDView
    |      |--> OrderCRUDViewModel
    |      |--> OrderListView
    |      |--> OrderListViewModel
    |--> Accounts
           |--> AccountCRUDView
           |--> AccountCRUDViewModel
           |--> AccountListView
           |--> AccountListViewModel
    ...etc
```

Answer (score 12):

> How do you organize your Models/Views/ViewModels in WPF (Solution Explorer)?

I typically have the Model in a separate project.  One of the main goals in MVVM is to keep the model isolated from the View and ViewModel entirely.

The View and ViewModel depends - My personal organization style differs based on project scope.

For very small projects, I often have the View and ViewModel for each "view" side by side.

For larger projects, I will separate these into their own namespaces (and folders), or even into separate projects.  Having the ViewModel in a separate project from the View is nice in that it can *enforce* that your ViewModel does not refer to View elements, as you can leave the required references out of that project entirely.

Comment: agreed/using same style, only comment I wanted to add was when the number of projects starts to grow - it starts to take a toll on app start-up time as each dll has to get loaded. I just refactored the app   I am working on that had 12+ dlls just for UI layer into 3 and used logical subfolder structure..

Comment: @denismorozov Or keep them separate, and use ILmerge/etc to consolidate afterwards in release: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx

Answer (score 3):

In a larger application you might wanna throw stuff into separate assemblies but I think this would work just as well.

```
Project MyApp
    |--> Views
    |      |--> AccountsView
    |      |--> OrderView
    |--> Sources
           |--> CustomerData
                  |--> Data
                  |     |--> DataAccess.cs    <-- Provides database search helper methods that return ObservableCollections of "Model" data types for use in the ViewModels.
                  |--> Models
                  |     |--> Account.cs
                  |     |--> Order.cs
                  |--> ViewModels    <-- Having more then one viewmodel for the same data is possible, e.g. Master-Detail scenarios.
                        |--> AccountsViewModel.cs
                        |--> OrderViewModel.cs
```

Answer (score 2):

I separated them into different projects then broke it down from there. Basically M project, VM project, and then the View as the main project. Though eventually V & VM became more tightly coupled.

Comment: Why are you tight-coupling your Views and ViewModels? Hence Reed's comment on **enforcing** MVVM through project separation. Or at the very least, use different namespaces for a similar effect.

Comment: @Heliac I realize this is 2 years later, but you are absolutely right. I ended up having to really decouple them as requirements for UX drifted.. having decoupled V's was a lifesaver!

Answer (score 1):

I'm a 'Solution Folder' person...

I keep a given V and VM together in the same assembly and put all V/VM assemblies in a 'Solution Folder' created by Visual Studio.

Models and Utility classes are isolated by assembly and also pushed into a 'Solution Folder'.

And of course, there's a Solution Folder called 'Infrastructure' that contains the magic strings and so on...

Solution Folders are a logical designation.  They do not create physical folders on your drive.

Answer (score 1):

This has been my starting basic setup for non trivial projects for almost a decade and it's simplicity has served me well. The terrible practice of keeping views and view models in the same project seems to be is a prism thing but the MVVM community shot that anti-pattern down a decade ago.

Client Tier:

```
ProjectName.Client.csproj
    --Assets
    --Images
    --Brushes
    --DataTemplates
    --Styles
    --Controls
    --Helpers
    --Views
ProjectName.Client.ViewModel.csproj
    --ModelViews
    --ViewModels
    --Helpers
```

Server Tier:

```
ProjectName.Server.Services.csproj
ProjectName.Data.csproj
ProjectName.Model.csproj
```

The view model layer doesn't reference a "Model" project as that exists in the server tier and is exposed to the view model via a proxy of the data service reference.